# Как получить тип размером на 1 больше, чем данный?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Как получить тип размером на 1 больше, чем данный `T` (в смысле минимальный по размеру тип, больше данного)? Для `T = int`, например, `long int`, если первый 4 байта, а второй 8. Или `long long int`, если `long int` тоже 4 байта, а `long long int` 8 байтов. Если бОльшего типа нет, то тот же самый тип вернуть (либо substitution failure). Можно ли это сделать без явного перечисления всех комбинаций через `std::conditional`?

Comment: Делать `struct` нужного размера :)

Comment: Нет, только руками перечислять.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat D:

Comment: Вместо перечисления всех комбинаций можно сделать список типов отсортированный по размеру и брать в нем следующий после типа с размером, равным размеру данного.

Comment: А "огласите весь список" - например, для `float` это обязательно `double`, или `long long` тоже годится?